# What is the difference between ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red) and providing one with ColorScheme.primary

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and did not get the difference. What is the difference between providing a color through

`primaryColor` like `theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red)`

AND

`colorScheme` like `theme: ThemeData(colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(primary: Color.red))`

So assuming this, If I set both `primaryColor` and `colorScheme.primary` to different colors, What change in UI we will get. Please check the example below:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final ColorScheme colorScheme = ColorScheme(
      primary: Color(0xFFFFFFFF), // <---- I set white color here
      primaryVariant: Color(0xFF117378),
      secondary: Color(0xFFEFF3F3),
      secondaryVariant: Color(0xFFFAFBFB),
      background: Color(0xFF636363),
      surface: Color(0xFF808080),
      onBackground: Colors.white,
      error: _lightFillColor,
      onError: _lightFillColor,
      onPrimary: _lightFillColor,
      onSecondary: Color(0xFF322942),
      onSurface: Color(0xFF241E30),
      brightness: Brightness.light,
    );
    return Theme(
      data: Theme(
        primaryColor: Colors.red, // <----- I set color to red
        colorScheme: colorScheme //  <----- colorScheme.primary is white
      ),
      child: child
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**ANSWER 2.0**

After a bit of a research, I want to tell you that, *Flutter is now moving toward using `ColorScheme()` extensively, and not `primaryColor` from `ThemeData()`*

Now coming to the point, first let us understand what these two are in our `ThemeData`

1. `primaryColor` is **responsible of setting the theme and background color of the app thorughout**
2. `colorScheme`, on the other hand is **a set of twelve colors based on the Material spec that can be used to configure the color properties of most components.**

**WHY PRIMARY, NOT COLORSCHEME:** This is because, if you want to use `colorscheme`, then you need to define all the predefined elements inside the `ColorScheme class`, which is not feasible in current case.

Also, primaryColor always is priority responsible for the theme of the app.

ColorScheme can be used to assign color to the widget like cards, materialbuttons etc, without even effecting the current theme of the app, with the usage of `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary`

Let us take a look at the example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ColorScheme colorScheme = ColorScheme(
    primary: Color(0xFFFFFFFF), // <---- I set white color here
    primaryVariant: Color(0xFF117378),
    secondary: Color(0xFFEFF3F3),
    secondaryVariant: Color(0xFFFAFBFB),
    background: Color(0xFF636363),
    surface: Color(0xFF808080),
    onBackground: Colors.white,
    error: Colors.redAccent,
    onError: Colors.redAccent,
    onPrimary: Colors.redAccent,
    onSecondary: Color(0xFF322942),
    onSurface: Color(0xFF241E30),
    brightness: Brightness.light,
  );

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.red,
        colorScheme: colorScheme
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

**USING PRIMARY COLOR AND COLORSCHEME IN MYHOMEPAGE**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container()
       )
    );
  }
}
```

So, if you closely, see this, the primaryColor is not mentioned in the `MYHOMEPAGE`, it will inherit it's parent `primaryColor`, not `colorScheme`.

[image: RESULTANT IMAGE 1]

Now, to note that, **colorScheme can be used explicitly to define the color of a widget.**

Also, colorScheme.copyWith() will do nothing but make changes to the color property inside the currently existing color, without effecting the global colorScheme color property, for instance primary.

Let us see the usage, if we want to use `colorScheme` in our theme

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary, // <-- Setting the color of the appbar explicitely using colorScheme
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container()
       )
    );
  }
}
```

Now we get this result, that the background becomes white now

[image: RESULTANT IMAGE 2]

### Gist

1. Theme `primaryColor` and other color property will always be preferred over `colorScheme`.
2. To use `colorScheme`, first you need to define your **custom colorScheme** in your **main.dart** file, and then make use by using in another instances for setting background etc.

In order to get more details, please read from these documentations:

- [ColorScheme Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html)
- [colorScheme property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/colorScheme.html)
- [Material Design](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation)
- [ThemeData Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html)

Comment: I am aware of using these two ideas you provided. But I am not getting the difference of setting the color property. What will be changed if I set color through `ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red)` and by setting the `primary` property of `colorScheme` in `ThemeData(colorScheme)`. What UI change will be achieved, If I set both to different. I will update the question if required, but now it looks to me fine. Thanks

Comment: @RahmatAli I have updated my whole answer. Hope it will help you :) Let me know

Comment: Thanks for such a big example. So it means we can set some secondary theme in our main `theme` by using `colorScheme` and we required it, we can use it . That's good.

Comment: Thank you @RahmatAli, that your question gave me a chance to explore more about flutter. Happy learning :)

Answer (score 0):

I am quite late for the party, but I'll just leave this here in case someone is still having trouble using colorScheme.

Although it is true that variables within colorScheme has to all be defined, we can avoid this and change only the parts of the variables we want with copyWith method.

```
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(primary: Colors.red)
```

I recommend searching and reading through the update notes from Flutter website.